# Dynamically created attribute on an JS object on the server disappears when sent to the client via jQuery Ajax call on a NodeJS/Express Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

On the client side I request via jQuery Ajax call a certain JS object.

```
$.get("/foo/requestData",function(data){
    console.log("Received data is missing added property: ", data);
});
```

On the server side I retrieve an array with JS objects after a DB request. I now create on that object a new property and want to send it back to the client:

```
  exports.requestData = function(req, res, next) {
    db.myDb.findAll({
      where: { bar: true },
      order: [
        ['id']
      ],
      include: [db.table1, db.table2, db.table3, {
        model: db.table4
      }]
    })
    .then(function(originalResultObject) {
      console.log("This is array with original Objects: ", originalResultObject);
      var newResultObject = originalResultObject.map(function(element) {
        var valueForNewProperty = "something new";
        var newProperty = "newProperty";
        element[newProperty] = valueForNewProperty;
        return element;
      });
      console.log("Added property is here: ", newResultObject);

      res.locals.thresholdSummary = newResultObject;
      res.send(newResultObject);
    })
```

As a result I get on the server:

> This is array with original Object:
>
> [Instance {dataValues: {foo: "bar1"}},
>
> Instance {dataValues:{ foo: "bar2"}},
>
> Instance {dataValues: {foo: "bar3"}}, ....]
>
> Added property is here:
>
> [{foo: "bar1", newProperty: "something new"},
>
> {foo: "bar2", newProperty: "something new"},
>
> {foo: "bar3", newProperty: "something new"}, ...]

But on the client site it is missing:

> Received data is missing added property:
>
> [{foo: "bar1"},
>
> {foo: "bar2"},
>
> {foo: "bar3"}, ...]

Probably it has something to do with the conversion of JS Object into JSON. The newly added property is ignored after the conversion into JSON while sending to the client. But how do I persistently add a new property on the server and send it to the client?

BTW: is the difference between the array at the very top saying "Instance {dataValues: ...}"?

Comment: What type of data is `originalResultObject`?  Is it an array of objects?  Is it some custom object from the database?  Your `console.log()` statements make it look like you're calling `.map()` on a plain object and expecting it to return another plain object.  It's very confusing.  Normally, `.map()` would be called on an array, but you don't show an array anywhere.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes originalResultObject is an array of objects, i.e. the "elements". On these elements I added a new property that I want to read out on the client side. The naming is indeed confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to the new property has to be added into the `dataValues` property of the originalObject, i.e.:

```
originalObject.dataValues.addedProperty = "something new";
```

Answer (score -1):

You are sending the response before the callback completes. Try this:

```
exports.requestData = function(req, res, next) {
db.myDb.findAll({
  where: { bar: true },
  order: [
    ['id']
  ],
  include: [db.table1, db.table2, db.table3, {
    model: db.table4
  }]
})
.then(function(originalResultObject) {
  console.log("This is original Object: ", originalResultObject);
  var newResultObject = originalResultObject.map(function(element) {
    var valueForNewProperty = "something new";
    var newProperty = "newProperty";
    element[newProperty] = valueForNewProperty;

    console.log("Added property is here: ", newResultObject);

    res.locals.thresholdSummary = newResultObject;
    res.send(newResultObject);
    return element;
  });

})
```

Note I moved the `res.send` up into the callback

Comment: That's not the callback but the map function. But thanks. Maybe I have to resolve the array with original objects with promise all.